# Setting fields in objects that need to build

Tags: object, constructor, machine-learning, standards

I have a DecisionTree object to create a Machine Learning model. DecisionTree has a lot of fields in it representing settings. Each field has a default value, and in most cases only one or two of these fields need to be changed.

The issue is, the DecisionTree is computationally expensive to actually build. So instead of constructing the model when it's made, I have the maker only parse and save the data. The model won't be built until DecisionTree.build is called. This allows for changing the settings before having to build. However, it also means DecisionTree.predict will fail if called before build is.

I know it's good practice to make Objects be in always a valid state. But this means building the tree in the constructor, which is expensive, and then if any settings are changed it has to be built again.

#### Example 1: Build call is seperate

```java
DecisionTree tree = new DecisionTree(data, classes, attributes);

tree.predict(item); //This would error

tree.maxDepth = 15;
tree.infoGain = 0.5;
tree.build();

tree.predict(item) // Now it would work
```

#### Example 2: Build call included, settings not in constructor

```java
DecisionTree tree = new DecisionTree(data, classes, attributes); // This would take a long time to complete

tree.predict(item); //This would now work

tree.maxDepth = 15;
tree.infoGain = 0.5;
tree.build(); // This would once again take a long time to complete

tree.predict(item) // Done, but takes twice as long as the previous example
```

#### Example 3

```java
DecisionTree tree = new DecisionTree(data, classes, attributes, null, null, 15, null, null, 0.5, null, null, null); // Settings are all included in constructor

tree.predict(item); //This would immediately be callable
```

My question is, are these 3 options the only ways to deal with many settings? What is the standard/best practice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it's a bad practice to fit algorithm with additional method, look for example at [scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py#L529), they provide additional methid to fit object, constructor itself just initializes internal variables, and if you call predict before fit it just throws NotFittedError. Besides that, maybe in future you would want to extend your algo to work for example with minibatches, and in this case it's impossible to call constructor more than once, thus you will need something like [partial_fit](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/stochastic_gradient.py#L488) method, to fit classifier on additional chunk of data. So you cannot do everything at constructor.

If you have a big number of parameters in initialization, maybe you will find useful [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)